# Best Data Structure representing Package Installation and System Dependencies

Tags: java, c++, c, go, data-structures

I'm trying to create a program (I choose Java but can be C/C++ or GoLang) based on an interview process to represent/simulate a Package Installation and System Dependencies like existent in Linux/Unix environments.
Basically, I'll do following requirements:

1) Maintain a record of installed packages and their dependencies.
2) Support explicitly installing a package in response to a command (unless it is already installed).
3) Support implicitly installing a package if it is needed to install another package.
4) Support explicitly removing a package in response to a command (if it is not needed to support other packages).
5) Support implicitly removing a package if it is no longer needed to support another component.

Before installing a package, automatically install all the packages it requires.
Before removing a package, confirm that no other packages require it. Dependent packages must be removed manually before the package can be removed.

I'd like tips of the best data structure (and the link that I can check) that I can use to do that. I tried using a List of queues as a way to store the dependencies and a Queue to store the packages installed but I'm not sure if this is the best approach like:

```html
...
ArrayList<Queue<String>> dependencies = new ArrayList<>(capacity);
Queue<String> pkgInstalled = new LinkedList<String>();
...
```

The process will capture the entry data from the user until an END command.
The command syntaxes are:

DEPEND item1 item2 item(n): Package item1 depends on package item2 (and item3 or any;

INSTALL item1: Installs item1 and any other packages required by item1.

REMOVE item1: Removes item1 and, if possible, packages required by item1.

LIST: Lists the names of all currently installed packages.

END: Marks the end of input, when used in a line by itself.

1) Follow each echoed INSTALL or REMOVE line with the actions taken in response, making certain that the actions are given in the proper order.
2) For the LIST command, display the names of the components currently installed.
3) For the DEPEND and END commands, no output, except the echo, is produced.
4) For the DEPEND command, there will only be one dependency list per item.

Comment: To be clear, your plan is to manage system level packages and dependencies with a Java virtual machine instead of using any of the existing system package management solutions? And, without looking at how any of them do it? I **admire** your optimism.

Comment: In fact is not a real system to manage dependencies and the pkg installation. I guess is missing to include that I'm looking to simulate the behaviour.
I choose Java, but if you believe another language like go or C/C++ is better, it'll be great to know

Comment: if it comes to "data structure", DAG is the first thing that comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the value of a `Queue` in this exercise (or a `LinkedList`) since you're going to want to be able to random-access the dependencies of a package.

I would suggest

```
Map<String, Set<String>> dependsOn = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Set<String>> requiredBy = new HashMap<>();
```

That way, when you delete a package, you can find all of the packages it has pulled in (`dependsOn.get(packageToDelete)`) and remove `packageToDelete` from each of their entries in `requiredBy`; if that leaves the `requiredBy` set empty, then that package can be removed too.

I would also suggest using a `Set` for the dependent packages to be added when you're adding a new root package.  It doesn't really matter what order you process them in, and it's more useful to be fast and avoid duplicates.

Originally I assumed that it would be simpler - easier to code and debug - to use unique fully-qualified package names as keys.  This requires a way to look up a package based on its name, but that should already exist.  However, if you prefer, you could implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` for your `Package` class and use them directly as `Map` keys.

In order to clarify how this might work, here is an example:

```
public Set<String> addDependencies(Item pkg, Item... dependencies) {
    Set<String> pkgDependsOn = dependsOn.get(pkg.getFullyQualifiedName());
    if (pkgDependsOn == null) {
        pkgDependsOn = new HashSet<>();
        dependsOn.put(pkg.getFullyQualifiedName(), pkgDependsOn);
    }
    pkgDependsOn.addAll(Stream.of(dependencies).map(dep -> dep.getFullyQualifiedName()).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    return pkgDependsOn;
}
```

(I might have used `Map.merge()` instead, but after writing it out I thought it was complex enough to be confusing.)

Returning the resulting `Set` of dependencies is probably overkill, but I can imagine some cases where it might be useful.

If you do choose to use the packages themselves as keys, it looks like this:

```
public Set<Item> addDependencies(Item pkg, Item... dependencies) {
    Set<Item> pkgDependsOn = dependsOn.get(pkg);
    if (pkgDependsOn == null) {
        pkgDependsOn = new HashSet<>();
        dependsOn.put(pkg, pkgDependsOn);
    }
    pkgDependsOn.addAll(Arrays.asList(dependencies));
    return pkgDependsOn;
}
```

I'm also not doing error-checking (like if you make a package depend on itself), null checks, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidW. I'm imagining how this works if I include the list commands for each line:

DEPEND TELNET TCPIP NETCARD;  DEPEND TCPIP NETCARD; DEPEND DNS TCPIP NETCARD; DEPEND BROWSER TCPIP HTML 

Where DEPEND is the command and I can repeat until I want to store dependencies.

Comment: Additional @DavidW, I was thinking about the queue because I can't remove a package if there are dependencies installed. 
Like if I try to remove NETCARD, I can't do it because there are dependencies installed as TELNET and TCPIP.

Comment: @EdsonMartins Checking if removing a package is possible should be as simple as verifying `requiredBy.get(packageToDelete).isEmpty()`.  As you remove it, if it leaves any other packages orphan, you can add those to a `Set` to be processed next - again, order doesn't really matter, they're already orphans.

Comment: Great @DavidW but my question is about the String key. What's supposed to add as a map key (Map <Key, value>)?
Could you give me a simple example when creating and adding each line as DEPEND value1 value2 value3 (just remind that I can have more than one DEPEND command) ?